# Adding TextViews dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I'm working on a project which asks true-false questions on android. While asking, it collects the questions, the given answers and the correct answers into a `Results[]` object array. After the user finished with the questions the `ResultsActivity` starts and I'm struggling to show the results in the following format:

Line 1: First Question

Line 2: The correct answer, the user's answer

Line 3: Second Question

....

I'll attach the `ResultsActivity` and the `content_results.xml`. Could you help me to get on the right path with this?

```
public class ResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextView questionText;
    private TextView resultText;
    private TextView givenText;
    private LinearLayout rContent;
    private LinearLayout rSecondaryContent;

    private void ResultQuestionFiller(int i){

            rContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.results_content);
            questionText = new TextView(this);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams fullWidth = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            questionText.setText(Results.True_False_Results[i].getQuestionResourceId());
            rContent.addView(questionText, fullWidth);
        }

    private void ResultAnswerFiller(int i){

        rSecondaryContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.results_content_secondary);
        resultText = new TextView(this);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams splitWidth = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        if (Results.True_False_Results[i].isTFgivenAnswer() == Results.True_False_Results[i].isTFcorrectAnswer()){
            resultText.setText(R.string.right_answer);
            resultText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#009933"));
        }
        else{
            resultText.setText(R.string.false_answer);
            resultText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

        givenText = new TextView(this);
        givenText.setText(String.valueOf(Results.True_False_Results[i].isTFcorrectAnswer()));
        rSecondaryContent.addView(givenText,splitWidth);
        rSecondaryContent.addView(resultText, splitWidth);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        for (int i = 0; i < Results.True_False_Results.length; i++ ){

            ResultQuestionFiller(i);
            ResultAnswerFiller(i);

        }


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

And the `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="hu.david.szablyteszt.ResultsActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_results">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/results_content">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/results_content_secondary"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

With that Code, I keep getting the following results:

Line 1: All The correct answers, the users answer in a line.

Line 2: Question 1

Line 3: Question 2

...

Comment: Better use adapter and listview with custom layout.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 this isn't his problem. It looks like he is still trying to learn, so I think list views can wait. I do agree that it would be better though. That said; @DávidCsurgó `rSecondaryContent` is horizontal, and you're appending to it each time. That's why you see all correct and user answers in a single line at the top (its the first child of `rContent`)

Answer (score 0):

Using a ListView or a RecyclerView would be much more efficient. Here is the code to achieve what you want using a RecyclerView:

Create an object to hold question, user answer and correct answer:

```
public class QuestionAnswerObject {

    private String question;
    private String userAnswer;
    private String correctAnswer;

    public QuestionAnswerObject(String question, String userAnswer, String correctAnswer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.userAnswer = userAnswer;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public String getUserAnswer() {
        return userAnswer;
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer() {
        return correctAnswer;
    }
}
```

ActivityMain layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

RecyclerView item layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userAnswer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/correctAnswer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView adapter:

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ObjectHolder>

{

    private ArrayList<QuestionAnswerObject> questionAnswerObjects;

    public static class ObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView question;
        TextView userAnswer;
        TextView correctAnswer;

        public ObjectHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            question = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.question);
            userAnswer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userAnswer);
            correctAnswer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.correctAnswer);
        }

    }

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<QuestionAnswerObject> data) {
        questionAnswerObjects = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
       ObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new ObjectHolder(view);
       return dataObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ObjectHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.question.setText(questionAnswerObjects.get(position).getQuestion());
        holder.userAnswer.setText(questionAnswerObjects.get(position).getUserAnswer());
        holder.correctAnswer.setText(questionAnswerObjects.get(position).getCorrectAnswer());
}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
    return questionAnswerObjects.size();
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        ArrayList<QuestionAnswerObject> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new QuestionAnswerObject("question1", "userAnswer1", "correctAnswer1"));
    data.add(new QuestionAnswerObject("question2", "userAnswer2", "correctAnswer2"));
    data.add(new QuestionAnswerObject("question3", "userAnswer3", "correctAnswer3"));
        mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(data);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
    }
}
```

An here in the sc[image]reenshot you can see the result: